# Find the value of I?

Tags: number-theory

[image]
Let $a, b, c$ denote the lengths of the sides of a triangle and let $p, q, r$ be real numbers in descending order. Also let $I=a^2(p-q)(p-r)+b^2(q-r)(q-p)+c^2(r-p)(r-q)$. Then what will be the value of $I$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Substitute $a=1, b=1, c=1, p=3, q=2, r=1$. Now try with a few more numbers. What can you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose without loss of generality that
$$\color{cyan}{a^2}\leq\color{green}{b^2}\leq\color{brown}{c^2},$$ and $$p=q+\alpha\color{blue} d,\quad q=r+\color{blue}d,$$ for some real $\alpha\geq1$ (the case $\alpha\leq1$ can be treated similarly).

So $$\color{red}{(q-r)(q-p)}=\alpha\color{blue}{ d^2}<0\leq \color{red}{(r-q)(r-p)}=\color{blue}{d^2}(\alpha+1)\leq\color{red}{(p-r)(p-q)}=\alpha(\alpha+1)\color{blue}{d^2}.$$

Then, by [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality), 
$$\eqalign{I&\geq\color{blue}{d^2}\times(-\alpha \color{brown}{c^2}+\color{green}{b^2}(\alpha+1)+\color{cyan}{a^2}\alpha(\alpha+1))\\&=d^2\times(\alpha(a^2+b^2-c^2)+a^2\alpha^2+b^2)}.$$
By [the law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), $a^2+b^2-c^2=2ab\cos\theta$ for some angle $\theta$. So $$I\geq d^2\times(a^2\alpha^2+b^2-2ab\alpha)=d^2(\alpha a-b)^2\geq0.$$

---

Please point it out if there are any inappropriate points or errors.

Hope this helps.